# How to prevent a cookie replay attack?

Tags: security

As a result of a security audit, we must prevent an attacker from being able to do a *cookie replay* attack. Apparently [this weakness has been around in the .NET framework for ages](https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/cookie-replay-attacks-in-aspnet-when-using-forms-authentication). There is also an old [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/900111) on that subject.

In contrast to the workarounds mentioned in the MS KB, the blog post recommends to mitigate this weakness by implementing the following:

- When signing in, set a boolean session variable to `true`.
- When signing out, set the session variable to `false`.
- Check the session variable on each request. If the value is `false` (or non-existing), return `not authenticated`.

Is this method sufficient to prevent a cookie replay attack? If it is, we would like to implement this in Sitecore in a way that developers don't have to think about it. Our idea is to override Sitecore's `FormsAuthenticationProvider`:

- Override all three `Login` methods and initialize the boolean session variable if login succeeded.
- Override the `Logout` method to set the session variable to `false`.
- Override the `GetActiveUser` method and take action if the conditions are not met.

But how to override `GetActiveUser` exactly? Do we return `Context.Domain.GetAnonymousUser() ?? Domain.GetDefaultAnonymousUser()`, like the `AuthenticationHelper` class does when there is no valid user?

Or is there a better way to transparently implement this in Sitecore?

Relevant information:

- Website is only accessible with https
- Cookies are already flagged as `httponly` and `secure`
- On log out, we call `AuthenticationManager.Logout();` and `Session.Clear();`
- Sitecore v7.2 rev 140314
- .NET 4.5

Comment: I would find a way to bind a session with a specific IP, upon login, and when checking for the authenticated user, make sure the IP of the request matches the IP bound to the session.

Comment: @adragomanov Binding it to a IP address is not safe in my opinion. User can be on same network, can spoof his IP, etc.

Comment: Sure, but I wouldn't worry about that. Spoofing the IP could only allow you send information to the server, but not receive the response back. With that said, using Anti-Forgery Tokens to validate incoming requests won't allow the attacker to do any actions on behalf of the user, since they won't be able to get a valid token, unless ofc, they're able to sniff one from a legit user request. Which brings us to your other concern. If the attacker is on the same network, then stack could easily do a MitM attack and then there's little to nothing you can do to protect that user inho.

Comment: For checking authenticated user, you could also do this:
1) On successful login, set the user info in session object. This could be just the username or a custom object depending on your requirements.
Eg: HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUser"] = "abc"
2) Then, in your application where you require to check if the user is logged in, check that session variable. I would also recommend checking for null as per defensive programming principles.
3) On logout, make that session variable null. Something like this:
HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUser"] = null

Hope this helps

Comment: The benefit of using session would be no dependency on cookie for authentication as cookies are very vulnerable to various attacks. Also, it is generally a good practice to null out the session variables on logout instead of making them false.

Comment: Is this just to cover the public website, the Sitecore login page or both?

Comment: @AlistairDeneys It is to cover the public website. But it wouldn't harm if the same is applied to the Sitecore login page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems I was very close with overriding Sitecore's `FormsAuthenticationProvider`. With our first attempt we could successfully prevent cookie replay attacks, but we were unable to access the Sitecore backend!

Only `GetActiceUser()` is called when signing in to the Sitecore backend, the other methods not at all. So, on recommendation of Sitecore Support, we just call `base` when we are on the Sitecore backend.

Here is the custom provider:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Security.Accounts;
using Sitecore.Security.Domains;

namespace Custom.Security.Authentication
{
    public class CustomFormsAuthenticationProvider : Sitecore.Security.Authentication.FormsAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private const string LoggedInSessionKey = "LoggedIn";
        private static readonly string[] SitesToSkip = new[] { "shell", "login", "admin" };

        public override bool Login(User user)
        {
            if (!base.Login(user))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (IsValidSite())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[LoggedInSessionKey] = true;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override bool Login(string userName, bool persistent)
        {
            if (!base.Login(userName, persistent))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (IsValidSite())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[LoggedInSessionKey] = true;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override bool Login(string userName, string password, bool persistent)
        {
            if (!base.Login(userName, password, persistent))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (IsValidSite())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[LoggedInSessionKey] = true;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override void Logout()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null && HttpContext.Current.Session[LoggedInSessionKey] != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(LoggedInSessionKey);
            }

            base.Logout();
        }

        public override User GetActiveUser()
        {
            if (!IsValidSite() || IsMarkedAsLoggedInOrNoSession())
            {
                return base.GetActiveUser();
            }

            return Context.Domain.GetAnonymousUser() ?? Domain.GetDefaultAnonymousUser();
        }

        private static bool IsValidSite()
        {
            return !SitesToSkip.Contains(Sitecore.Context.GetSiteName(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public static bool IsMarkedAsLoggedInOrNoSession()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current == null
                || HttpContext.Current.Session == null
                || HttpContext.Current.Session[LoggedInSessionKey] != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to let Sitecore know about your custom provider. Change `web.config` as follows:

```xml
<authentication defaultProvider="forms">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="forms" type="Custom.Security.Authentication.CustomFormsAuthenticationProvider, Custom" />
  </providers>
</authentication>
```

All this is wrapped up in a (personal) [blog post on preventing cookie replay attacks in Sitecore](https://thomasddn.blogspot.be/2016/10/easily-prevent-cookie-replay-attacks-in.html).

Comment: Fantastic answer and great tie in to your blog. Love it!

Comment: The config changes apply to the `sitecore/authentication` section of the config files (not necessarily in web.config), not `system.web/authentication`.

Answer (score 1):

I would abandon the session if the variable is not present or false. Sitecore should do the rest. You can also explicitly logout the current user before abandoning the session.

Comment: Where and when exactly should we validate the session variable? Keep in mind that we opt for a (reusable) solution that is transparant for the developers, i.e. in some provider, pipeline or event.